# Android Activity not found

Tags: android

I have a problen that I MUST to solve today. My program not find an activity. The file of Activity exist, and it's declared on manifest.

I call the activity with this code:

```
Intent intento = new Intent(this, Hide.class);
startActivity(intento);
```

Activity:

```
public class Hide extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager(); 
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),   PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
}
```

Comment: Post your entire manifest.

Answer (score 4):

Register Activity as in Manifast if it's in another package :

```
<activity
    android:name="teru.SimDetect.TFC.Hide"
    android:label="Hide" >
</activity>
```

Comment: @user1686776 : ok post now your new log and also declare all activity in Manifast as we declare Hide .means `android:name="<FULL_PACKAGE_NAME>.ACTIVITY_NAME"` for all activities

Comment: The error is the same as I declare in the first post, is unable of find Hide activity.

Comment: and also post your full manifest and packages name for more help

Comment: Complete manifest added, for see my files tree, please see the image clicking the link

Comment: Are you doing pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED... somewhere else on the app? Maybe on a class that's executed before the Hide activity?

Comment: @user1686776 : you can try it to run after commenting these lines in Hide Activity

Comment: I do it, but this is not the problem, the problem is that the application doesn't found hide class activity.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<activity
android:name=".Hide"
android:label="Hide" >
</activity>
```

Don't use package name.

and use like this to call an activity

```
Intent intento = new Intent(YOUR_PRESENT_CLASS.this, Hide.class);
startActivity(intento);
```